# ClassPool.getDefault is throwing exception. How to resolve this

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault(); //getting NoClassDefFoundError here
```

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ibatis/javassist/ClassPool*

Comment: Yes it is NoClassDefFoundError. Can you please help me here to resolve this issue

Comment: you are compiling with a jar that has that class and at runtime that class is not present

Comment: I have ClassPool class in External libraries- if the class is not present in the runtime, what is the process to have that class in runtime

Comment: If anyone knows how to resolve this issue, please ping me here.

Comment: you want to solve this fast - I get it, but the problem is pretty simple and there are a ton of posts here on SO about this

Comment: First I have gone through the solutions in SO, If you find any suitable solution for this type of question or If you know the solution you can please ping me here.